# How would you name the function that takes a list of lists [L1, L2, L3] and returns a list of lists [l1, l2, l3]

Tags: naming

What would you call the function that takes a list of `n` lists of values, and returns a list of all the unique lists of length `n` where the `i`th element is chosen from the `i`th input list?

For example:

```
[[a,b], [c], [d, e]]
=>  [[a,c,d], [a,c,e], [b,c,d], [b,c,e]]
```

At first I called it `permute`, but then I realized that would be the function that takes a single list and return all possible orderings, e.g.  `[1,2,3] => [[1,2,3], [1,3,2], [2,1,3], ...` or something similar.

Comment: I would call it "combinations".

Comment: Huh. I just noticed this question was closed. That's dumb. I mean, are people just gonna close every `naming` question then? I don't see how other questions under this tag could be any less opinion-based.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's calculating a [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product). In particular, it's an `n`-fold Cartesian product, given that there are `n` lists to combine.

Comment: *The* Cartesian product :).